# How can I check disk usage for all filesystems

Tags: bash, awk

I have few servers and few disks on servers. I can check disk usage with awk like this:

```
/Disk123/1231/11 100TB 63TB 38T 63% /homeblablabla

disk1=$(df -h | awk '$1=="'"$diskpath1"'"{print $5}')
```

It's work, checking filesystem and print usage. But some servers df output not like usual. Filesystem is too long and usage side go to next line, like this:

```
/Disk12313242/232414/2342342/
                       100T   63T  38T  63% /home/blablabla
```

So I must check like this:

```
disk1=$(df -h | awk '$5=="'"$diskhome1"'"{print $4}')
```

How can I check all filesystems and when if any filesystem is 100%, write to disk1 variable?

Comment: Which OS/distribution do you use?

Comment: Use `df`'s option `-P`.

Comment: You could also try an alias:
    <code>alias df="df | awk 'NF == 1 {printf(\$1); next}; {print}'"</code> (http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/8268/df-without-line-wrap-on-long-fs-name)

Comment: df -P fixed my next line problem, thanks.

Comment: Btw: if you're looking for a more human readable output with long lines: `df -P | column -t`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `-P` switch, the problem should not appear anymore. From

```
man df | less +/'^ *-P'
```

:

```
    -P, --portability
           use the POSIX output format
```